# Interpreting mediation analysis results with non signiciant p-values, when individual tests were significant

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, mediation

I am running a mediation analysis like so:

```
model.M <- lmer(Enjoyment ~ Stimulus + (1|P_ID), mydata)
model.Y <- lmer(Flow ~ Stimulus + Enjoyment + (1|P_ID), mydata)

results = mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat='Stimulus', mediator='Enjoyment',
                   boot=TRUE, sims=100)
summary(results)
```

The lmer of Enjoyment ~ Stimlus + (1|P_ID) shows a significant effect of stimlus.

The lmer of Flow ~ Stimlus + (1|P_ID) also shows a significant effect of stimlus.

I find it therefore a bit stange that there is no direct effect below. Am I correct interpreting that there is no mediation effect from the Enjoyment variable?

Both Stimlus and P_ID are categorical variables (is.factor = TRUE).

Mediation analysis:

```
Causal Mediation Analysis 

Quasi-Bayesian Confidence Intervals

Mediator Groups: P_ID

Outcome Groups: P_ID

Output Based on Overall Averages Across Groups 

               Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value
ACME              0.160       -0.314        0.660    0.56
ADE              -0.618       -1.052       -0.193    0.00
Total Effect     -0.458       -1.064        0.142    0.15
Prop. Mediated   -0.206       -8.064        6.886    0.70

Sample Size Used: 114
```

Simulations: 500 
--update--
Some additional information:

```
> model.M <- lmer(Enjoyment ~ Stimulus + (1|P_ID), mydata)
> anova(model.M)
Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
         Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value   Pr(>F)   
Stimulus 21.228  4.2456     5    90  3.4809 0.006373 **
```

and

```
> model.Y <- lmer(Flow ~ Stimulus + Enjoyment + (1|P_ID), mydata)
> anova(model.Y)
Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
          Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F.value  Pr(>F)    
Stimulus   5.044   1.009     5  88.915   2.088 0.07431 .  
Enjoyment 70.916  70.916     1 102.678 146.753 < 2e-16 ***
```

In order to run the mediation analysis, I have to detach(package:lmerTest, unload=TRUE).

Strangely also, during the mediation analysis I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat = "Stimulus.f", mediator = "Enjoyment",  :
  treatment and control values do not match factor levels; using BmBmGG-BmBmGG and BmGDA-BmGDA as control and treatment, respectively
```

Comment: Please confirm, in the 2nd model, the Enjoyment effect is n.s. Also, ¿what do you get for a p-value for the slope if you do Flow ~ Enjoyment?

Comment: I've added the information in the original question. My concern is that Stimulus doesn;t have a significant effect in the last model. So why is the ACME p-value so high?

Comment: ¿Is Stimulus a categorical variable?

Comment: Stimulus is indeed a categorical variable

Comment: ¿How is this variable being treated in the mediation analysis? If it is being treated as a scalar variable, this could be the cause of the problem here.

Comment: Stimulus contains a text label, not sure if that's possible to be mistreated? How do I correct this? Stimulus <- factor(Stimulus) ?

Comment: If the mediation analyses is indeed treating the Stimulus variable as a factor, then this would suggest that you have true mediation: no direct effect, only an indirect effect.

Comment: Does this mean that a high p value for ACME means that there is a mediation effect?

Comment: I've ran everything with proper factor assignments and I've update the question. I do receive a warning message "treatment and control values do not match factor levels". No idea what it means.

Comment: If ADE is significant. Does that mean there is full mediation? I'm sorry I'm trying to understand how mediation analysis works still.

Comment: Trying to locate information about ADE and ACME in the mediate R package...

Comment: ACME = average casual mediation effect & ADE = average direct effect; these p-values suggests that there is a statistically significant direct effect, but no mediation effect.  ¿What happens if you predict Flow only from Stimulus?